# How do 'Sum' time in decimals for result in hours and minutes in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I total hours and minutes shown as decimals?

For example 1.45 represents 1 hour and 45 minutes plus 1.40 (1 hour and 40 minutes) summed to give me 3.25 (3 hours and 25 minutes) instead of 2.85?

Comment: Uh, 1.75 would be 1h 45mins... So 1.45h + 1.40h would in fact be 2.85h.

Comment: Doesn't the spreadsheet's built-in "date" format do that? And formatting a result cell as decimal or something else would show the decimals?

Comment: Like david said, 1.75 would be 1hr 45min (1hr + 3/4 of an hour = 1.75). If you want your decimals to look like 1.45 for 1hr45min, use a custom number format. Right-click the cell, select **Format Cells**, Click **Custom**, and then enter `h.mm`

Answer (score 1):

One time column and replace the . with a : and then excel will know your dealing with time data and do the math correctly.

Comment: +1 - Absolutely. Unless you have a good reason not to then using hh:mm values will be easier in the long run in most situations